# top n record of each group by active record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called result and it has `source_id`

```
id source_id text order
1  1         aaa  1
2  1         bbb  2
3  1         ccc  3
4  2         aaa  1
5  2         bbb  2
5  2         ccc  3
```

the question is how getting top 2 record order by order of each group by source_id? the result should be like this

```
source_id  text  order
1          aaa   1
1          bbb   2
2          aaa   1
2          bbb   2
```

I tried these queries and non of them are working

```
.group("source_id").order('order DESC').limit(30)

.group_by(&:source_id).map! { |source_id, latest_results_of_source| latest_results_of_source.limit(30)}

.group_by(&:source_id).map { |source_id, latest_results_of_source| latest_results_of_source.limit(30)}

.group_by(&:source_id).map { |source_id, latest_results_of_source| latest_results_of_source}
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Result.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source_id ORDER BY order DESC) AS r, results.* FROM results) x WHERE x.r <= 2 ORDER BY order")
```

Comment: @Arash jan I have mysql and your code is not working there :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 Result.where(order:[1,2]).order(:source_id, :order)
```

Comment: And for readability I would rename the order field to something else (ex. sort_order)

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for, i don't know how many group do i have to put it in where clause . it should be dynamic

Comment: It is dynamic. The only part you need to specify is is whatever top n you want. where(order:[1,2])  is the same as  where("results.order <= 2").  'order' is a column and you want the top 2's.